# Visual C++ Error C2146

Tags: url, variables, c++-cli, browser

everyone,
     I was trying to compile a program using C++/CLI to check my stocks, but I ran into an error when I put the variable in the URL. Can anyone help me, please?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->webBrowser1->Navigate("http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s="num".HK+Interactive#chart1:symbol="num".hk;range=1d;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined");
}
```

Oh, and by the way, this code is from a "Windows Forms Application" and the name of the variable is "num". Again, I would appreciate any help if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Are you attempting to insert the value of num into your URL, or are you trying to actually put the string "num" into your URL?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I've edited the tags -- this is C++/CLI, *not* C++.

Comment: Sorry everyone, due to my simple _(too simple)_ question, I am unable to provide you all with the information you need. Please check out my other question, if you may (I only asked 2 questions). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't doing anything to build the string. I've never done managed C++, but I assume you can't do this:
`"http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s="num` and get what you want. In C#, you could just use operator+: `"http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=" + num`, or use StringBuilder, or String.Format. I'd imagine there's something similar in managed C++.

Comment: I have already built the string for my program, and I want to insert the value of "num" into the URL. Oh, and the value of "num" if from a textBox. Thanks for the quick answers, and can anyone please post a sample of code I need to use? Again, thanks for the answers.

Comment: What does "already built the string" mean in this case? Is it a static string (except that you need the value of num plugged in) or is a dynamically built string?

Comment: OK, I aplologize. What I meant by "already built the string" is that I put `int num = int:: Parse(textBox1->Text);` in the code. Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: In addition to this problem, I forgot to mention another error (sorry). Here are all the total errors I received:

C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'num'
C2059: syntax error : ')'

They are all from the same line, which is:
`this->webBrowser1->Navigate("http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s="num".HK+Interactive#chart1:symbol="num".hk;range=1d;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined");`. Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think the problem is still what I said--you can't simply put the variable name in the middle of contatonated strings to make the strings append. sprintf is a way to do that with standard C string (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/). I don't know stl strings well enough to know how those factor in. In C#, you use System.Format, which you may be able to use in managed C++.