# C++/CLI: Inserting variables into strings?

Tags: string, url, variables, c++-cli

As you can see, I am trying to insert variables into strings. In my new finance program, I am attempting to insert the variables *(stock symbols)* into strings, which is the URL to the interactive charts in Yahoo! Finance. Here is a code sample from my failed program:

```
int num = int:: Parse(textBox1->Text);
// ...
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->webBrowser1->Navigate("http://finance.yahoo.com/blahblah/xxxxx"num"xxxxx"num".html);
}
```

In the code above, I tried to put the variable *num* inside the URL. I formed a string from bits and pieces. The only problem I have now is how to stick the variables in. Here are the errors I ran into:

> Warning - C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 123, Column: 14 --- Unexpected token for a 'term'.
>   
> Error - error C2146: syntax error : missing `')'` before identifier `'num'`.
>   
> Error - error C2059: syntax error : `')'`.

I would appreciate any help if possible. Please post any improvements, substitutes, or tips to help. You can also email me at `francislau97@gmail.com`. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ Error C2146](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783048/visual-c-error-c2146)

Comment: You should edit and improve your existing question (your new title is MUCH better, so is your explanation), instead of starting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
String::Format(gcnew String("http://finance.yahoo.com/blah blah/xxxxx{0}xxxxx{1}.html"),
              123,
              456);
```

(no compiler available to check actual code)

---

Here is my stab (still not compiled/tested) at integrating this into your snippet:

```
int num = int:: Parse(textBox1->Text);
// ...
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->webBrowser1->Navigate(String::Format(gcnew String("http://finance.yahoo.com/blah blah/xxxxx{0}xxxxx{1}.html"),
              num,
              num));
}
```

Comment: `error C3698: 'System::String ^' : cannot use this type as argument of 'gcnew'` I tried using `new`, but it told me to use `gcnew` instead.

Comment: i think i fixed it, will try with a MS compiler later